How to fingerpress scroll with puppeteer
I want to imitate a real finger scroll up/down on puppeteer. I use the mobile device configuration on puppeteer.
I don't know which event it is on a browser possibly wheel ? so I tried this,
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
var  {KnownDevices} = require('puppeteer');
const iPhone = KnownDevices['iPhone 15 Pro'];

async function r()
{
    var browserArray = []
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch(
        {   headless:false,
            defaultViewport: {
              width: 375,
              height: 667,
              isMobile: true,
            }/**/
    });



    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.emulate(iPhone);
    async function wheeler()
    {
        //query 
        await page.goto('https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook', {timeout: 0, waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});

        await page.mouse.wheel({deltaY: -30});

    }
    wheeler();
}

r();

this doesnt do anything, I could use ScrollBy with puppeteer but I want to imitate a  real finger press scroll event by a human.
As an example, for mouse wheel on browser, I can listen to the event like this:
document.body.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
  console.log("deltaY: " + e.deltaY)
});\

How to do the same on mobile browser with finger press scroll up and down ?
Update:
I found touchscreen and tried this to imitate scroll down/up on page with real fingerpress but it didnt work...
          await page.touchscreen.touchStart(0, 0);
          await page.touchscreen.touchMove(15, 15);
          await page.touchscreen.touchMove(30.5, 30);
          await page.touchscreen.touchEnd();


Does google.com have anything to scroll down to? I don't see a vertical scrollbar on it. Why do you want to do this exactly? This is uncommon; generally, locators will scroll the target element into view when you take an action on them, so no manual manipulation is necessary (we assume browser scrolling works and doesn't need to be tested, since it's part of the browser software, not the application under test. For scraping, there are other page-specific ways to scroll when necessary than a finger scroll).

yes I can scroll down with my mouse wheel, with the config await page.emulate(iPhone); so it does have the scroll. google.com with a random search has a scroll down button, I am updating the code

Also I specifically want to use fingerpress scroll down, i dont know why page.touchscreen didnot work

Thanks, although I'm still not clear why you want to do this. What's the point/goal exactly?

I want to use a mobile agent to scrape a website, and I want to learn how to use fingerpress scrolls in the meantime, because I might need that to avoid WAF. @ggorlen

Makes sense, it might be good to edit the post to clarify that this is mainly for WAF avoidance practice, then we can remove these comments.
